# Spoiler markup required

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, spoilers

We need the [spoiler] markup tag, similar to Aruade or SciFi.se, since we'll be discussing various puzzles/riddles where knowing the solution spoils the whole challenge. That way, the answer won't spoil the puzzle for the visitor.

Answer (score 9):

Spoiler markup is already built into the system

> Spoiler text here

Simply add `>!` before your spoiler

e.g.

```
>! Your spoiler text goes here
```