# Definition of quality contents

Tags: discussion

I wrote a [small puzzle](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/11952/answer-this-question-with-exactly-one-correct-answer), which was downvoted badly either because not many people understood it or it has severe content quality problem. I assumed the second and raised a flag to request the post deletion.

Moderator response for the flag is:

> declined - your question has upvoted answers, and we prefer not to
>   delete others' high quality content, if possible.

I remember the question [Problem in the middle of desert](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/4939/problem-in-the-middle-of-desert/4942) was deleted which had even more upvoted answer. (The answer I gave had ~50 net upvotes).

So what prevents first question from deletion while the other was deleted ruthlessly?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The "Problem in the middle of the desert" question was actually deleted because it was astroturfing a particular website, not because deletion was requested. That was one of many questions coming in linking back to that particular site.

Either that, or it [was plagiarism, which is deleted](https://puzzling.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1348/a-policy-on-plagiarism).

Comment: Thanks. But after looking [another post](http://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/12129/how-many-would-die-after-e-slightly-pushes-the-structure-in-front-of-him), it appears my understanding of puzzling.stackexchange ideology is incorrect and I should avoid adding low quality contents.