# Issues surrounding copyright material and puzzles from other sites

Tags: support, moderators, legal, site-promotion

[This question](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/15832/planet-of-animals) has a picture that is "© 2001 - 20th Century Fox - All Rights Reserved" according to IMDB, from where it appears to be sourced. The puzzle has been published on [another site](http://www.mindpuzzle.me/planetofanimals/), although the puzzle itself doesn't appear to be plagiarism (the user posting this puzzle appears to have created it on both sites) I can't help but think using copyright movie images might be a problem. Can the moderators say what the policy on this sort of thing is?

Comment: Related: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/185934/policy-on-uploading-copyright-protected-images-to-imgur

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I can tell, the image augments the description of the puzzle and could easily be removed. That's not to say the image *should* be removed, but just that the post won't be harmed much if it were. Stack Exchange sites have a clear process for handling copyright violations as explained in point 16 of the [Terms of Service](http://stackexchange.com/legal/terms-of-service). Neither the moderators nor any other user is obligated to enforce copyright law. (Which is good because law is a highly technical field.) We have a "Designated Agent" for just this purpose.

We generally [frown on plagiarism](https://puzzling.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1378/15), but, as you say, it's hardly a concern if the author submitted to both sites. As a courtesy, adding a link from one version to the other seems in order. (I see that the author has [already done that](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/revisions/15832/2).)