# Why was this well-received question deleted by a moderator?

Tags: discussion

With reference to the question:

[Which playing card replaces the question mark?](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/17435/which-playing-card-replaces-the-question-mark/)

I don't understand what criteria was used to delete this question. The question received 8 upvotes and got 3 answers. The highest voted and accepted answer received 13 upvotes. The next answer got 9 upvotes and the last one got 3 upvotes. Each of the answers were similar but had a different methodology to arrive at the solution. The question was viewed 1168 times before being outright deleted by moderator Emrakul. The only negative feature about the question could be the fact that it was one of a series of 3-4 questions posted by the OP in quick succession. However, I don't understand why a well-received question should be deleted. The upvotes and views should in fact be an indicator that this was a diamond in the rough that can and should be retained.

**DISCLAIMER:**
The accepted answer is mine and therefore I would like to inquire what the criteria for deletion is so that I do not invest any time in questions that will be deleted altogether despite their positive reception.

I would really appreciate it if moderator Emrakul himself could shed some light on the question deletion policy.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

This question was deleted as one of many recent plagiarized posts. For more information, see [our policy on plagiarism.](https://puzzling.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1348/a-policy-on-plagiarism)

My apologies for the inconvenience. It can be a little unclear when questions are deleted for this reason. It's very unfortunate that you lost rep as a consequence, and we come down pretty hard to discourage plagiarism in the future.

Also, *thank you so much* to those who have been flagging plagiarism. It's *very* helpful.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying this quickly. From now on I'll preferably do a plagiarism check before taking the time to post an answer

Comment: @CodeNewbie Yeah, I'd recommend that. (Note that puzzles coming from an unclear source aren't likely to be deleted, but puzzles coming from an identifiable source are.) Also feel free to flag those posts, as that will also help a ton.