# Do we need an "original" tag?

Tags: discussion, tags

Many users, like me, are spending a lot of time and effort to create original and creative riddles. Whereas other puzzles seem to be either copied form somewhere else or look like old riddles passed on through generations (which explains why they sometimes get solved pretty fast).

I can see there is no point in defining rules to allow or disallow certain types of riddles but I'd feel better about both writing and solving riddles if there was a tag indicating whether a riddle is original or not. There is some magic to it, at least for me there is.

What do you think?

Comment: Like [chestnut](http://meta.puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/3009/is-chestnut-a-meta-tag) and [challenge and solution-unknown](http://meta.puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/1268/burninate-i-know-the-answer-and-i-dont-know-the-answer), that would be discouraged because it is a meta-tag.

Comment: @f'' I strongly disagree here. "Original" would not only usefully describe the nature of the puzzle (like math or computer) and is not opinion based at all. So how do you draw your connection to your references?

Comment: How does "original" describe a puzzle like "math" or "computer-puzzle" does? Given a puzzle and its solution, it's possible to decide whether it's a math puzzle or not. It's not possible to classify a puzzle as "original" based only on its content. "Original" would be a meta tag because it describes the context of the puzzle, not the puzzle itself.

Comment: @f'' Okay sensei. How about his: "A riddle gives indirect clues about an unnamed object or concept to be identified [...]" funnily enough happens to be the most used tag in this community. GIve me a break :D

Comment: Downvotes are often used on Meta to indicate disagreement with an idea, or to indicate that the idea isn't well-based or strongly developed. It doesn't prevent discussion on the idea, but it _is_ intended to serve as feedback. That being said, I've edited the meta-question back out, since it's not directly relevant to the question here.

Comment: Well, the Emrakul can't be countered it seems ;)

Comment: @Avigrail I have no idea what point you're trying to make about the "riddle" tag.

Comment: When you say "riddles" in this question, do you mean puzzles in general or only [tag:riddle]s?

Answer (score 6):

I don't think we need this tag for multiple reason :

- There is a [policy](https://puzzling.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1348/a-policy-on-plagiarism) that requires posters to mention the source of the puzzle if it is not the poster's original creation. You can assume every puzzle without any sources is an original creation.
- Almost every puzzle would be under the tag "original", "common knowledge" or "traditionnal" so it would force every puzzle to use one of this tag, which is a lot of work
- If you want people to know that the puzzle is your own work you can say it in the post (before the puzzle, as a "introduction")
- It will never be 100% clear what "original" means :

  - If I take an existing puzzle and change a few things/parameters is it original ?
  - What if I "create" a puzzle that appears to be very similar to another puzzle ?

Comment: I agree it would be hard to define

Comment: I disagree with your first point - that policy is unenforceable in the case of common riddles because it becomes impossible to specify the original source that is being plagiarized from. (I have flagged one such question before, the flag was marked helpful but the question was not deleted because they couldn't find a "verbatim original source".)