# A preemptive request to prohibit puzzles from the redesigned Temple of Quetzalcoatl

Tags: discussion, puzzle-series

So I've started redesigning the Temple of Quetzalcoatl with a new set of questions. I posted a few puzzles from the old Temple as exemplars before that, but a few days after I'd posted the second one, somebody else chimed in asking for help on that exact same question.

Would it be okay for me to report such asking-for-help questions as being from the Temple and asking that they be deleted?

Comment: @Emrakul, this seems like a question for you, since you're our house expert on plagiarism.

Comment: Do you know if there's a point at which you'd call the Temple _finished/completed_ (like a contest)? If so, we might be able to treat it like that: delete the question until it's over, then undelete them.

Comment: It's not so much a contest as it is a challenge for anybody to do at any time, but I suppose once I've finished writing all 260 levels we can bring them out of hiding.

Comment: @JoeZ. 260 levels ... is that likely to happen within the next several years?

Comment: I think given the current attention it has (and that it has a Facebook page that I actively advertise) I might be able to finish it within a few years, yes.

Answer (score 2):

Obviously, [plagiarism is not okay](https://puzzling.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1344/is-it-acceptable-to-copy-and-paste-questions-from-other-sites), so you could always try to have questions deleted on those grounds. That being said, if the post is significantly more than just a link to the Temple of Quetzalcoatl -- if the poster has rewritten the question sufficiently and cited it -- I'd have trouble being convinced that the question isn't suitable for this site.

Normally, posting puzzles here that are from other websites is welcomed so long as they don't exist on Puzzling yet, so this is an interesting one. I'm not completely familiar with Stack Exchange's policy on plagiarism, but copying of questions isn't a problem in most other communities. [This question talks about copied *answers*](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/160077/users-are-calling-me-a-plagiarist-what-do-i-do), but that isn't quite the same.

From what I understand, if questions on Puzzling follow the same rules as answers, I don't think there's any valid reason they could be deleted so long as the poster cited the source and didn't just copy-and-paste the question.

Comment: If the post didn't have the same content and the same answer as the Temple, then it would be a different puzzle in its own right, and I'd be totally fine with having that puzzle there.

Comment: And in the case that the content of the puzzle is different, I'd prefer they *not* reference the Temple of Quetzalcoatl in their adaptation.