# Unable to find a referred-to meta post

Tags: discussion

[This puzzle](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/a/18477/14279) says there is more information on meta about its locked status, but I can't find the meta post this refers to. Could someone point me in the right direction, or clarify whatever it was that was meant to be clarified?

Comment: Perhaps @Emrakul could help point to the meta post he said he made?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It might've been a little unclear based on the content dispute lock message, but [I left a comment on the post](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/18476/rebus-for-those-who-strive/18477#comment58827_18477) suggesting that anyone who wants to discuss spoiler tagging go to Meta.

The reason I locked the post was because arguing in edits is not constructive, and is just going to result in a sequence of rollbacks. It's locked temporarily to prevent people from trying to add spoiler tags [against the previous thoughts on Meta](https://puzzling.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1360/39) without further discussing it (or alternately the issue will drop).

Feel free to post new thoughts and/or ask a new question, though.

Comment: I guess it is rather ....-- I guess the best word for it would be "oil-based" ---.... but I supposed I see where you're saying from. Thank you for the response.